# Saturation of Analytic sets is Anayltic

Tags: analysis

Let $X$ be Polish and $E$ an analytic equivalence relation on it.  So,
$E ⊂ X × X$ is analytic. Show that if $A ⊂ X$ is an analytic set then
the $E$-saturation of $A$, the set $[A]_E =\{x ∈ X : ∃y ∈ A (x E y)\}$ is analytic.

Since $A⊂ X$ is an analytic set then there exists a Polish space $Y$ and continuous Borel function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $f(Y)=A$.

Don't really know where to go from here.

I was thinking about using the fact that $A$ is analytic if and only if there exists Polish $Y$ and Borel $B⊂ XxY$ with $A=$proj$_X(B)$.

Comment: Isn't it true that $[A]_E = \phantom{}$proj$_X((X\times A)\cap E)$?

Comment: Yes I believe so.  So, if that's true then does [A]E being analytic follow immediately?

Comment: You may need to check up on some of the closure properties of analytic sets (projection, formation of Cartesian product or intersection...).